# Esse tipo de validação de segurança é valido? (Varios if vericando se o VALIDATE é true)

Tags: php

O seguinte modo é correto para validar se os valores recebidos por inputs são validos?

```
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hemocomponenteBolsa', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
    {
        if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'grupoSanguineoBolsa', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
        {
            if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fatorRHBolsa', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
            {
                if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dtVencimento', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))
                {
                    if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'statusBolsa', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
                    {
                        #CÓDIGO
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
else
{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><b>Atenção!</b>
                         Falha ao cadastrar. (Erro 007)</div>";
    header("Location: ../view/novaBolsa.php");
}
```

No caso aqui, eu removi vários campos pra efeito de aprendizado, mas possuo **12** `inputs` para serem recebidos, então ficaria com **12** vezes `if(...)`, é correto fazer do modo anterior ou isso faria o sistema ter uma lentidão?

Comment: Construa um array e valide todos com um laço

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize o [filter_input_array](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input-array.php) e depois com [in_array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php) e [array_values](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php) verifique se existe algum valor `FALSE` nos valores, ***exemplo***:

```
<?php

    $filters = [
        'hemocomponenteBolsa' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
        'grupoSanguineoBolsa' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'fatorRHBolsa' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'statusBolsa' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'dtVencimento' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
    ];

    $result = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filters);

    if (!in_array(FALSE, array_values($result), TRUE)
    {
        //#Codigo
        //A variavel $result tem os valores corretos
        $result['hemocomponenteBolsa'];
    }
```

não esqueça que a configuração foi inserido dentro de um `array` com as variáveis que vem do seu [html](/questions/tagged/html) com os filtros configurados [e existe outras formas de configurar, essa é a mais simples](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input-array.php).

Assim seu código seria muito fácil para dar manutenção, inserindo ou removendo outros campos somente na variável `array` `$filters`, e não precisa escrever tantas estruturas de decisão (`if`) que são desnecessárias nesse caso e atrapalham o entendimento do código e a sua manutenção.

---

Caso você queria que o campo `dtVencimento`, possa passar sem valor teria que montar uma função auxiliar e nela se existir valor, fazer o filtro pelo [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php) e se não mandaria o valor padrão, **exemplo**:

```
<?php

    function testString($value)
    {
        if (mb_strlen($value) > 0)
        {
            return filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        }
        return "";
    }

    $filters = [
        'hemocomponenteBolsa' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
        'grupoSanguineoBolsa' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'fatorRHBolsa' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'statusBolsa' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'dtVencimento' => array('filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,'options' => "testString")
    ];

    $result = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filters);

    if (!in_array(FALSE, array_values($result), TRUE)
    {
        //#Codigo
        //A variavel $result tem os valores corretos
        $result['hemocomponenteBolsa'];
    }
```

***Referencias***

- [filter_input_array](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input-array.php)
- [in_array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php)
- [array_values](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php)

Comment: Muito boa resposta Virgilio! Só tive um pequeno problema, tenho um input (observações) que pode vir uma string ou pode não vir nada, vazio no caso, que filtro eu poderia usar? Usando sua ideia, ficou do seguinte modo:
`$filters = ['hemocomponenteBolsa' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
  'grupoSanguineoBolsa' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
  ...
  'obsBolsa' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
];`

Só que se eu usar o FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING e ela vier vazia, vai achar um `false`, como eu poderia fazer? Tentei atribuir manualmente um valor padrão caso a variável viesse vazia, mas não deu certo.

Comment: @GabrielQ. fiz a edição com mais um estilo de codigo! .

Comment: Excelente resposta Virgílio! Consegui implementar seu códigos e suas ideias no meu sistema e além disso, aprendi muitas coisas novas nessa resposta. Obrigado mesmo!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, troque o `in_array(FALSE, array_values($result))` por `in_array(FALSE, array_values($result), true)`, isso irá [prevenir o PHP de converter](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/92e0703c77af489b63313ad45c06119a5a72d64b).

Comment: @Inkeliz já foi adicionado o último paramento como dito no seu comentário, realmente tem que colocar devidor valor `0` que pode ocorrer em alguns input. Obrigado.

Comment: @GabrielQ. faltou colocar um paramento que o Inkeliz, mencionou nos comentários devido a digitação no `input` de um `0` teria um efeito inesperado, é só colocar TRUE no último parâmetro do `in_array`!